# Can values in a column (such as names) be used in an email body string?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal: An Excel spreadsheet with VBA code, where
- User ID in Column A is used for the sending address.
- user's first name in Column B is used in the greeting line of the email body.

What I have: I created multiple emails with an email body for each User ID in Column A.

What I cannot figure out: How to use the name from Column B in the email body.

For every email:
[image]

Here is the code thus far, asterisks have been used to replace email text.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant, lr As Long

    Dim strbody As String

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    strbody = "Hello " & vbNewLine & _
         "***********************" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "***********************" & vbNewLine & _
         "***********************" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "***********************" & vbNewLine & _
         "***********************" & vbNewLine

    For i = 2 To lr
        With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
            .Subject = Range("C2").Value
            .To = Range("A" & i).Value
            .Body = strbody
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "*****"
            '.Send
            .display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
        End With
    Next i
    'MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Move the creation of `strBody` *inside* the loop and concatenate (`&`) in the user name from column B (`Range("B" & i).Value`).

Comment: Ok, I had tried the (Range("B" & i). Value but never with strbody within the loop

Comment: You can also create the `strBody` outside the loop, with a placeholder like `"[User Name]"`, and then just `Replace` the placeholder inside the loop with `Range("B" & i).Value`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I really appreciate it that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Couple things... **First:** qualify your ranges. `Range().value` versus `workbooks().sheets().range().value` could be problematic depending on what is active. **Second:** do the Excel stuff separate from the Outlook stuffs to avoid some performance issues. Create a string and store as a variable, then append said variable to the email.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the value from cell(2,i) to .body in the loop like below

```
  `Sub SendEmail()
     Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant, lr As Long

     Dim strbody As String, Strbody1 as String

     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     strbody = "Hello " 
     strbody1 = vbNewLine & _
          "***********************" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "***********************" & vbNewLine & _
          "***********************" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "***********************" & vbNewLine & _
          "***********************" & vbNewLine

     For i = 2 To lr
         With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = Range("C2").Value
        .To = Range("A" & i).Value
        .Body = strbody & Range("B" & i).Value & strbody2
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "*****"
        '.Send
        .display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
End With
    Next i
    'MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing
    End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Will give my comment as an answer:

First, do the Excel activities at once, storing what's needed in variables so you're not changing focus back and fourth between Excel/Outlook:

```
Public toString as String

Private Sub excelActivities()
    with thisworkbook.sheets("NAME")
        dim lr as long
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        dim i as long
        for i = 2 to lr
            toString = toString & ";" & .Cells(i,1).Value
        next i
    end with
End Sub
```

Then you can use your Excel values, stored as variables, when performing your Outlook activities... could be two separate subroutines called in series:

```
Sub generateEmail()
    excelActivities
    outlookActivities
End Sub
```

Your `outlookActivities` would include creating the email, adding the `.To = toString`, etc.

Comment: Postscript; you could also use functions or something in a single subroutine for generating the string, as to avoid having public variables, but would still group the excel activities to occur before the outlook activities to avoid swapping focus.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will play around with it to see what I come up with.